# Просчитывание индексов куба

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, геометрия

Перед отрисовкой куба задаю его вершины:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
      0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
      0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
     -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
      0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
      0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
     -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
     -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
};
```

Теперь нужно определить индексы, но я не знаю как
Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть способы?

Comment: Для тех кто не знаком с OpenGL близко, поясните о каких индексах идет речь.

Comment: @Cerbo скорее всего имееются ввиду индексы массива `vertices` образующие грани куба при помощи 2 треугольников и 4 вершин.

Comment: @Cerbo именно так, как ampawd и написал

Comment: могу ошибаться. но. индексировать надо точки имеющие одинаковые координаты и лежащие на одной плоскости. а в вашем меше я таких не нашел. следовательно индексировать просто нечего.

Comment: @perfect у него вершины куба - там все банально индексируется

Comment: @ampawd , может я просмотрел, покажите совпадающие вершины (хотя бы две)

Comment: @perfect  грань куба ( квадрат) образуется двумя трегольниками у которых две вершины общие - посмотрите на картинку приклепленную в моем ответе

Comment: @ampawd , а теперь понял в примере уже проиндексированный вертексный массив. а я подумал что он не проиндексирован.

Comment: @perfect а как этот массив мог быть не проидексированным по вашему?

Comment: @ampawd минутку, сейчас попробую его нарисовать. так не пойму

Comment: @ampawd , вот так выглядит не проиндексированный куб. следите за логикой: 3 вершины в 1 тругольнике, в 1 грани куба 2 треугольника = 3 * 2 = 6 вершин, в кубе 6 граней = 6 * 6 = 36 вершин в кубе, а в вопросе их 8.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48836/discussion-between-ampawd-and-perfect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то, что вы просите называется индексный буфер, так как у вас 8 вершин определено для куба, то рисовать придётся при помощи индексов массива `vertices`, и например режима `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`

каждая 4 рка индексов определяет одну грань куба двумя треугольниками для которых две вершины будут общими.

у куба `6` граней, следовательно необходимо `4*6 = 24` индекса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

взависимости от того в каком порядке записаны позиции каждой вершины в массиве `vertices` будут зависеть индексы в массиве `indices`, тоесть для вашего случая будет что то типо

```
GLushort indices[] = {
 0, 3, 1, 2, // нижняя грань
 2, 6, 3, 7, // левая грань

 //... остальные 4 попытайтесь сами определить
 // обход против часовой стрелки по дефолту
};

//...

//  далее в цикле отрисовки
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Comment: Хорошо, но я так и не понял как можно узнать indices

Comment: @andrew нарисуйте куб на бумажке, пронумеруйте вершины отсчитывая впорядке в котором у вас они в массиве `vertices` далее выбираете 4 индекса для каждой грани - что конкретно не понятно

Comment: @andrew добавил картинку для лучше понимания

Comment: спасибо, так гораздо понятнее

Comment: `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` достаточно сложное решение для такого случая. Лучше и проще `GL_TRIANGLES`

Comment: @Kromster так и знал что кто то заметит этот безобидный TRIANGLE_STRIP )) чем сложное то?

Comment: @Kromster здесь это не столь значительно - так как автору надо было понять принцип индексного рендеринга

Comment: @Kromster чем `GL_TRIANGLES` лучше? 36 индексов будет, а в случае с `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` 24 - экономие памяти

Comment: Сами же пишете, топикстартеру надо понять "принцип индексного рендера", а не ломать голову как рисовать развертку куба для inverted-Z-обхода ;-)

Comment: @Kromster я думаю топикстартер уже понял этот принцип )

Comment: Кстати, а вы сможете написать порядок вершин в стрипе для куба? Ведь они не квадратами идут,  как кажется из вашего утверждения, про 4 х 6 = 24. Загуглите картинки по GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP для примера.

Comment: @Kromster моё утверждение лишь говорит о том, сколько нужно индексов если использовать стрип

Comment: @Kromster я то могу написать этот порядок, одним стрипом вполне можно получить куб

Comment: Значит вы не понимаете как работает GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, если считаете, что нужно 4*6=24 индекса. Вот кстати решение: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375338

Comment: @Kromster я прекрасно понимаю как `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` работает, так как вполне можно 24 индексами получить куб при помощю `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48852/discussion-between-ampawd-and-kromster).